# Loading a view for a specific time period

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

From my viewcontroller view I am loading a xib file. I want this view to be shown only for, say 3 seconds. After that I have to remove this view. Should I use NSTimer here or is there a better way to show and remove this view. Thanks.

Comment: i think  your loading ViewController acts like splash screen, when your application launch. if i m right you can refer this tutorial:http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-splashscreen-display-in-the-iphone/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in `viewDidLoad`

```
[self performSelector:@selector(RemoveView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```

Add this method in your class

```
-(void)RemoveView
{
//Remove your view here..
}
```

Also setUserInteraction to NO to your view